# Is the collection $\mathcal T_{\infty} =\{ U\mid X-U$ is infinite or empty or all of $X\}$ a topology of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the collection $\mathcal T_{\infty} =\{ U\mid X-U$ is infinite or empty or all of $X\}$ a  topology of $X$?

$X- \emptyset$ and $\emptyset -\emptyset$ holds so $X$ and $\emptyset$ are in $\mathcal T_{\infty}$
$$X-\bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} = \bigcap (X-U_{\alpha})\subset (X-U_{\alpha}^{*})$$ So this holds.
$$X-\bigcap_{i} U_{i} = \bigcup (X-U_{i})$$
How can I explain this part? Need help!!

Comment: Have you tried checking for all the conditions one by one? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: The countable intersection part!!

Comment: Showing finite intersection is enough!

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877773/is-the-collection-tau-infty-ux-u-is-infinite-or-empty-or-all-of-x-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $X= \mathbb{R}$, $U_k^c = \{1,k,k+1,... \}$. Then $\cap_k U_k^c = \{1\}$.

Note that each $U_k$ is in $T_{\infty} $ but $\cup_k U_k$ is not.